# Why does my text object look weird along its edge?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, text-object

I am new to blender, and after I created a text object, I found it had a black material along its edge.

Here is view display and render display, which shows the problem. I don't know understand what is causing this. It looks unrealistic and bad—is there any way to beautify it?

[image]

[image: Render image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly it's because of default Smooth shading (Normals) on extruded part of Text object.

[image]

You can fix that by adding **Edge Split** modifier.

[image]

Or you can search **Convert to Mesh** and enable under Data Properties > Normals > **Auto Smooth**. But you would not be able to retype your text.